# How do I find duplicates within Pandas dataframe and plot a scatter of the overlapping values?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, scatter

I have a data frame which is an hourly time series over a 1 year period. There are two variables for each hour, tp1 and tp2:

```
                      tp  tp1
             time                         
2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  NaN
2013-01-01 00:30:00  0.0  NaN
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.0  NaN
2013-01-01 01:30:00  0.0  NaN
2013-01-01 02:00:00  0.0  NaN
                 ...  ...
2013-12-31 22:00:00  0.0  0.0
2013-12-31 22:30:00  0.0  0.0
2013-12-31 23:00:00  0.0  0.0
2013-12-31 23:30:00  NaN  0.0
2014-01-01 00:00:00  NaN  0.0
```

In the time series, two identical times and dates exist. However, it only shows either tp or tp1 the first time, and the other variable shows as NaN. The second time that same time shows up, the other variable will show.

I'm trying to find a way to identify the duplicate times and dates, and take the value of tp1 and tp, negating the NaN values, for example:

```
                      tp  tp1
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.05  NaN
2013-01-01 01:00:00  NaN   0.07
```

The desired output would look as follows:

[image]

I've tried writing my own if statement within a for loop, however, I can't get very far and I end up confusing myself every time, so apologies if this is an easy trick that I'm missing here!

Comment: The plot does not match the last example, right?

Comment: What do you mean by negating the NaN values?

Comment: I mean to ignore them and only plot the values that are numbers greater than 0. So in that last example, for 2013-01-01 01:00:00 I'm looking to end up with only tp=0.05, tp1=0.07. Then from there, I'd plot 0.07 onto the x-axis and 0.05 onto the y-axis. Then move onto the next hour and keep adding plot points

Comment: And yes, the dates are different on the plot I showed, apologies if I've made it confusing to read, just put it to show the general layout of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You want to plot only the duplicated points which have values greater than 0.0 in tp and tp1, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

If your DataFrame is as follows, meaning for each column there are no duplicate time where the data is not na:

```
                    tp      tp1
2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.05    NaN
2013-01-01 01:00:00 NaN     0.07
```

Then you can fill na with 0 and sum:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tp':[0.05, np.nan], 'tp1':[np.nan, 0.07]}, index = ['2013-01-01 01:00:00']*2)

df.fillna(0).groupby(df.index).sum()
```

to get:

```
                    tp      tp1
2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.05    0.07
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
data = [['2021-01-01 00:00:00',   0.0, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:01:00',   pd.NA, 0.0],
        ['2021-01-01 00:06:00',   0.0, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:13:00',   0.0, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:13:00',   pd.NA, 0.0],
        ['2021-01-01 00:14:00',   0.5, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:14:00',   pd.NA, 0.7],
        ['2021-01-01 00:15:00',   0.0, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:16:00',   0.7, pd.NA],
        ['2021-01-01 00:16:00',   pd.NA, 0.9]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'tp', 'tp1'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)


df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby("time").sum().
                   query('tp>0.0 and tp1>0.0').plot(x='tp',y='tp1', ', marker='o')
```

[image]

[image]